# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No wrapped connection. in android

Tags: android

My ListView activity is force closed automatically after sometime. my ListView has some TextView and image which is getting from parsing but after loading some image its automatically force close...
LogCat info

```
06-25 16:29:31.238: W/SingleClientConnManager(706): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
06-25 16:29:31.238: W/SingleClientConnManager(706): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
06-25 16:29:31.988: W/dalvikvm(706): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No wrapped connection.
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.assertValid(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:163)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.getRemotePort(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:314)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:137)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpProcessor.process(BasicHttpProcessor.java:290)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.preProcess(HttpRequestExecutor.java:160)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:401)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.apps.moviesearchapp.services.HttpRetriever.retrieveStream(HttpRetriever.java:63)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.apps.moviesearchapp.ui.UpcomingAdapter$BitmapDownloaderTask.doInBackground(UpcomingAdapter.java:133)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at com.javacodegeeks.android.apps.moviesearchapp.ui.UpcomingAdapter$BitmapDownloaderTask.doInBackground(UpcomingAdapter.java:1)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-25 16:29:32.098: E/AndroidRuntime(706):  ... 4 more
06-25 16:29:34.928: D/dalvikvm(706): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1533K, 59% free 3051K/7367K, external 3067K/3245K, paused 2122ms
06-25 16:30:15.378: I/Process(706): Sending signal. PID: 706 SIG: 9
```

My bitMapDownloaderTask is

```
private class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        url = params[0];
        InputStream is = httpRetriever.retrieveStream(url);
    if (is==null) {
            return null;
        }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {           
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my   `httpRetriever.retrieveStream`

```
      public InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        return getResponseEntity.getContent();

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }


    return null;

}
```

please help...

Comment: which URL you are passing ??

Comment: "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92"+movie.PosterPath (movie.posterpath is .jpg path of the movie)

Comment: try to access your URL in browser...its invalid

Comment: looks like you have several http clients working simultaneously and having common resources

Comment: my url is working fine... some image of the movie showing correctly but after 5 to 6 second its force closed.. @Prag's sir pls help

Comment: barn.gumbl sir, pls help

Comment: thanks  @barn.gumbl sir... i got some idea from your comment and i correct it